# Iterating over a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bN5p.png)

Newbie here. I want to iterate over this list of dictionaries to get the "SUPPLIER" for every dictionary. I tried

```
turbine_json_path = '_maps/turbine/turbine_payload.json'
with open(turbine_json_path, "r") as f:
    turbine = json.load(f)
    # print((turbine))

    for supplier in turbine[0]['GENERAL']:
        print(supplier["SUPPLIER"])
```

But I get a type error.. TypeError: string indices must be integers

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the image is attached in the hyperlink on top.

Comment: Paste the dictionary (or sample of it) as text, not image.

Comment: FYI `print(supplier["SUPPLIER")` is missing a `]`

Comment: `for supplier in turbine[0]: print(supplier['GENERAL']['SUPPLIER'])`

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for d in turbine:
    print(d["GENERAL"]["SUPPLIER"])
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. can you please tell me how to replace the value of "SUPPLIER"? I tried... if (d["GENERAL"]["SUPPLIER"]) == "": d["GENERAL"]["SUPPLIER"] = "0" .... but this doesn't work.

Comment: Actually it should work. Why do you think it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one supplier key in your dictionary, so it would be

```
supplier = turbine[0]['GENERAL']['SUPPLIER']
```

Other wise your for loop is looping over the keys within the `'GENERAL'` dictionary, which are strings.